# How to split .log into two files

Tags: logging

I have a files in .log format and I want to have two files with in the first files the first 5k lines and in the other the rest of the files.
Can you help me to do this please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This commande lines help me to do it

```
head -n5000 files.log >files_5k.log

tail -n+5000 files.log >files_+5k.log
```